# Get value from specific javascript object attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the **locations** array from my javascript object and store it.

```
data = [{
          "id":123,
          "name":"John",
          "locations":["Smith","McHale","Residence 4"]
        }]
```

I've tried things like:

`locations = data['locations']` and `data.locations`. But both return `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? How can I just grab the locations array to store in its own variable? (Not using Jquery) Thank you for your help advance!

Comment: As nicael alluded to, you don't need `[ ]` on an object. Using those brackets will put it in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's array first, and only then object:

```
locations = data[0].locations;
```

You could avoid `[0]` this if you remove `[` and `]` from your `data` declaration.

Comment: You answered so quickly it wouldn't let me. Done! Thanks again :D